# Rubyなどを使って検索できるプログラムを作りたい

Tags: javascript, ruby, html, css, postgresql

下記のようなプログラムを作りたいと思っています。

１．氏名、住所、生年月日が登録できること。
２．氏名と住所があいまい検索できること。
３．生年月日が範囲検索できること。
４．２と３の検索結果を一覧表示できること。
　　表示する項目は氏名、住所、年齢
５．４で表示した一覧から選択を行い修正ができること。

開発言語はHTML&CSS,JavaScript,Rubyの中から作りたいです。

また、データの登録先はデータベースでもファイルでも構いません。
データベースの場合はＰｏｓｔｇｒｅＳＱＬがいいと思っています。

上記のプログラムを作って、データベースに登録する場合、
どういう言語のどういう知識が必要になるのでしょうか？

また、何から勉強していけばスムーズでしょうか？

プログラミングドど素人なので的確な質問になっていませんが、
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: はじめまして、質問の範囲が広すぎるように感じます。もう少し質問絞っていただくか、もしくはご自身で試して見た結果、詰まってしまったところを質問してはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 挙げられた言語の候補を見る限りはブラウザから操作する「webアプリ」を想定しているのでしょうが、ご本人が「何をどこまで理解しているか」を第三者から判断できないため、どこからアドバイスしたらよいのか難しく感じます。例えばRubyが候補に挙がってますが、これはある程度使えるからなのか(他にもPHPなどの選択肢がありますよね？)。『ど素人なので0から勉強するつもり』だと、本一冊になる内容になる気がします。

Comment: 残念ながらここはチュートリアルを主眼としたサイトではないので、どこから始めたらいいのかわからないと言った内容の質問はあまり歓迎されません。「HTML&CSS,JavaScript,Rubyの中から」と書かれていますが、その全ての知識が必要になるでしょう、またサーバ構築の知識も必要になります。RubyでWebアプリを作成するにはRailsというのを使うのが普通です。まずは「Ruby on Rails」の入門書や入門サイトで概要だけでも理解していただいて、その中でわからない部分について質問の範囲を絞り込んであらためてご質問いただいた方がいいように思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。勉強して自分で作ってみてから改めて質問したいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

rails + postgres を選択し、 postgres であいまい検索を行うクエリを発行していくことが、もっとも近道な気がしています。

参考:
[PostgreSQLでFuzzy Searchを試す](https://takuti.me/note/postgresql-fuzzy-search/)
[PostgresSQL: Documentation: fuzzystrmatch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)

上記のページでは、  Levenshtein distance (編集距離) によるクエリを postgres の上で実行する方法について述べています。

ただ、実際に日本語(というかマルチバイト文字)の取り扱いを postgres のあいまい検索エンジンがどれほどうまく取り扱ってくれるのかを、自分は知らないので、事前調査が必要だと思っています。

Comment: リンク先を確認しました。今の知識ではちょっと難しいように感じました。最低限どういう知識があれば理解できるでしょうか？